# Set Working Directory with Relative Path in Rscript

Tags: r

I'm new into R and I'm writing a Rscript. I need to set a different Working Directory with relative paths in my Rscript. Is there a way? I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look to [This page](http://rfunction.com/archives/1001)

Comment: @Smich7 I already tried but it doesn't work. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Then show what you tried it could helps

Comment: This is where I need the workingdirectory: <pre>pressione <- scan("C:\\Users\\utente1\\Desktop\\Prova_Meteo\\data.txt")<code> I need to change the path to a relative one.

Comment: I don't undersatand what you really need. what you gave is not a relative path and it's pointing on a file. I guess you want to set `C:\\Users\\utente1\\Desktop\\Prova_Meteo`. You can do `setwd('C:/Users/utente1/Desktop/Prova_Meteo')` and `pressione <- scan('data.txt')`

Comment: What `getwd()` gives you ?

Comment: This is what I get with getwd(): "C:/Users/user1/Documents". But I need to use this script on different PCs,so I need relative paths.

Comment: Install `rstudioapi` package, do `library(rstudioapi)` and `setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))` If you can't install the package make sure you have a recent version of rstudio.

Comment: Is there any other way, without packages? Anyway, when I run the script, it says: "RStudio not running". And yeah, I installed the package.